# iTunesconnect : renaming app name to app name which has been already removed

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm updating the name of my application by submitting new version of it. 
But when I rename the app I get the message that the app name has already need used.

Actually before I've created an app with the new name but have removed long long time ago.

From [here](http://hesh.am/2012/01/recovering-a-deleted-app-name-in-itunes-connect/) I know that it can be easily done by changing the localization name of the application description, let say from English to UK English. But what can I do if the application language I chose was let say German, I can't to something even similar to German.

Is there any way to change the name of the app?

Comment: Consider following the [App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, perhaps you can try emailing Apple.

Comment: Once you deleted a name, you can't use that name ever again.

Comment: Hah, then why its possible to do by changing the localization of the application description ?

Comment: I mean whats the logic behind I'm really curious about what Apple wants to handle with this

Answer (score 1):

You can't change name of application once you have uploaded it. Apple was allowing earlier delete App from iTunes. But, now a days they are not allowing to delete app. So, you need to take another name for application. You can give same name for displaying on app. But, for displaying in iTunes, you have to take unique name.

Comment: Apple allows to change application name by submitting a new version of it

Comment: One question I have, I want my current app to be renamed to a "lite" version and use the original name with my "full" version. So say I have an app named "MyApp". I want to now rename that to be "MyApp lite" and then create a new app called "MyApp". Will that be allowed, or will iTunes complain that "MyApp" has already been used?